# Do I have to add_filter() before apply_filters() in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, filtering

I'm trying to understand Wordpress plugin like:

apply_filters( 'gettext', $translations->translate( $text ), $text, $domain );

I'm looking for all codes in Wordpress, I can't find:

add_filter( 'gettext', ....);

Why there is no add_filter for this plugin?  Or I missed something?  Same thing like:

do_action('wp_loaded');

I can't find:

add_action('wp_loaded', ....);

Answer (score 8):

`apply_filters` is like, 'if there are any filters with this name, run the attached callbacks with these parameters'. So if there is no `add_filter` for that name, it means that there is no filter that's going to be run with the `apply_filters` call at the moment.

The same goes with `do_action` and `add_action`.

Comment: Thanks the reply. I was thinking it should be like what you say.  However, I was confused with WordPress, it keeps using apply_filters. Like in class-http.php, there is:  return apply_filters('use_http_extension_transport', function_exists('http_request'), $args ); Why they simply return function_exists('http_request') ?

Comment: `if there are any filters with this name, run the attached callbacks with these parameters` - where is it said in the wordpress doc site ?

Answer (score 2):

I am a beginner in PHP - WordPress stack as well, but this is from my understanding.

The plugins call `apply_filters` without having any `add_filter` in their codes is **to allow the website users to add custom logic to their plugins**. We - the users, can add our own function and use `add_filter` to register our functions.

For example, this piece of code is from the plugin. Normally, it shows all products but it provides us a way to not show a specific product.

```php
// Plugin's

if (apply_filters( 'plugin_show_products', true, $product->get_id() ) ) {
    $this->show_products();
}
```

So, if we - the users, want to customize a bit. We can add our own function as following (maybe in `functions.php`)

```php
// Our custom changes
function my_own_changes($boolean, $product_id) {
    if ( $product_id === 5 ) return false;
    return true;
}
add_filter( 'plugin_show_products', 'my_own_changes', 10, 2 );
```

This translates to: The plugin will behave normally but for my own site, it will not show the product with ID of 5!

Comment: Yes. I think that this behaviour is exactly what filters are made for.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this type of code in a plugin or theme where the `apply_filter` is used without necessarily having an existing `filter` or `add_filter`

In this case, where the `apply_filters` is used without a filter you will have to call the function again where you want to run it. For example, in the header of a theme.

The following is an example of apply filters used in a function that is again called in the `header.php`

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'header_apply_filter_test' ) ) {

    function header_apply_filter_test() {

        $filter_this_content = "Example of content to filter";

        ob_start();

            echo $filter_this_content; 

        $output = ob_get_clean();

        echo apply_filters( 'header_apply_filter_test', $output );//used here 
    }
}
```

Now in the `header.php` file, you would have to call this function since it is not hooked anywhere. So, in this case, to display the output in the header you would call the function like this :

```
<?php  header_apply_filter_test(); ?>
```

You could as well write this code with a hook and it would do the same thing i.e display the output in the header.

```
add_filter('wp_head', 'header_apply_filter_test');

if ( ! function_exists( 'header_apply_filter_test' ) ) {

        function header_apply_filter_test() {

            $filter_this_content = "Example of content to filter";

            ob_start();

                echo $filter_this_content; 

            $output = ob_get_clean();

            echo $output; 
        }
    }
```

For this second option, you would still have the capability of using apply_filters anywhere else to call the callback function `header_apply_filter_test()` since the filter now exists.

So the bottom line in my view is a ***use case*** since either approach works!